# How to merge several Github users?

Tags: github

I am newbie github users and mistakenly created two github user accounts. I'm wondering how can we merge two github users account into one, including their corresponding repositories? any idea?

Answer (score 0):

A quick [*something search*](http://arresteddevelopment.wikia.com/wiki/Do_a_something_search) will give you [this](https://help.github.com/articles/merging-multiple-user-accounts/):

> 1. Transfer any repositories from the account you want to delete to the account you want to keep. Issues, pull requests, and wikis are transferred as well. Verify the repositories exist on the account you want to keep.
> 2. Update the remote URLs in any local clones of the repositories that were moved.
> 3. Delete the account you no longer want to use.